# ServletContext.getAttributes("Name") returns null

Tags: java, servlets

I have written servlet.I want to test the functionality of `init()` method of my servlet.But when I written a test case for my servlet with `servletRunnermIt` gives following exceptions. Also I got just config and context object. If I want to get init-parameters from these two object, it returns null.

```
com.meterware.httpunit.HttpException: Error on HTTP request: 405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL [http://127.0.0.1:8888/NewsletterServlet]
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.validateHeaders(WebClient.java:623)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.updateClient(WebClient.java:500)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateWindow(WebWindow.java:192)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getSubframeResponse(WebWindow.java:183)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:158)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.getResponse(WebClient.java:122)
    at com.newscenter.server.NewsletterServletTest.testFetchNews(NewsletterServletTest.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Show your servlet code and XML configuration.

Comment: The exception has an entirely different cause than a `null` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The URL looks suspicious, http://127.0.0.1:8888/NewsletterServlet

Usually the servlet URL should contain the web application name, like http://127.0.0.1:8888/**WebAppName**/NewsletterServlet. But I don't see it in your case. That might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you've a

```
super.doGet(request, response);
```

in your servlet's `doGet()` implementation. Remove it.

The `HttpServlet` class is based on the template method pattern where all non-overriden `doXxx()` methods send a HTTP 405 error indicating that the method is not supported. When you override it, it would not send a HTTP 405 error, but just whatever result which is generated by the particular overriden method. But you would still get the 405 when you call the `super` method anyway.